# When in the game 2048 a new tile is not created?

Tags: 2048

I'm a newbie to Java.
I'm trying to create the game 2048 in NetBeans IDE.
So far I've managed to create the following:

1. Merging same tiles (when pressing keyboard arrows).
2. Moving tiles
   (when pressing keyboard arrows).
3. Creating a new tile at a random
   position with 90/10% chance of 2/4.

But!

The only thing that keeps me from finishing the game is creating the rule:
When the game stops creating a new tile?
In the image below I've shown some examples from the real game, when the game keeps the player from creating a new tile when pressing down arrow:
[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkVNj.png)

The same applies for the rest of the directions and the keyboard keys (Left, Right, Up).

Obviously, when part/s of the last row is filled with tiles, the player is unable to create a new tile when pressing down.
Or if two rows are filled, or three.

But is there any algorithm for that rule?

Is there a specific number of tiles that are on screen that prevent from creating a new one?

Or is there a specific score-step that creates the prevention?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about game rules / game design / app requirement / app specification instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

The game creates a new tile whenever at least one tile moves or merges.

```
If aTileMoved() Or aTileMerged()
    createANewTile()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to implement this rule and will see what happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this question is about programming (how to implement the mechanics) or if its more about 2048 (what the mechanics are).

If it is the former, then just check if any tiles moved or merged with other ones in the last move. If at least one tile moved or merged with another, generate a new one. If not, do nothing. Of course how easy that is to implement heavily depends on how you've written your game, and since you've provided no code, I cannot illustrate with an example.

If it is the latter then please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help center article on what questions are on topic here.